# search_path doesn't work as expected with currentSchema in URL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, search-path

I encounter difficulties when configuring a custom search path for SQL queries, specifically when trying to locate objects within the public schema. The problem arises when I specify the currentSchema parameter in the database connection URL, as it prevents successful access to the public schema, which is part of the default search path.
How could this be fixed?

The long story:

1. I have an application schema `app1`.
2. The DB has the Postgis extension installed in the `public` schema (and we want to keep it there).
3. The DB `search_path` is configured like this:

   ```
    ALTER DATABASE tst SET search_path = "$user", public
   ```
4. When connecting to the DB without specifying current schema in URL, the default schema is public and so it finds all the geo functions and objects. But I have to specify the `app1` schema prefix when addressing objects from `app1`, e.g.:

   ```
    select st_asgeojson(geometry,15,4) from app1.shapes limit 5
   ```
5. This is not convenient. So I added "app1" as a current schema parameter to the connection URL like this:

   ```
    jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tst?currentSchema=app1
   ```
6. Now, when I connect to the DB, I don't have to specify the app1 prefix when addressing objects from app1 schema. However, requests that involve Postgis objects don't work anymore and fail with:

> ERROR: function st_asgeojson(public.geometry, integer) does not exist

My understanding is that it should search for the objects in the `search_path` and find them in the `public` schema but it doesn't happen for some reason.
I've tried specifying search path on a user level as well but it still didn't work.

Comment: You do `SHOW search_path;` to figure what the current search path is. Can you try to do `SET search_path TO 'app1,public'` followed by `SHOW search_path;` to see if it worked?

Comment: When I connect without currentSchema parameter in the URL, the SHOW search_path returns "app1, public". Then, I disconnect, add  currentSchema=app1, and connect again. Now  SHOW search_path returns "app1".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parameter name `currentSchema` is a bit misleading. It takes the **whole `search_path`**, not just the "current schema". [The documentation:](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html)

> - `currentSchema = String`
>
> Specify the schema to be set in the search-path. This schema will be
> used to resolve unqualified object names used in statements over this
> connection.

So try:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tst?currentSchema=app1,public
```

There are various ways to pre-set the `searchpath` for a given user. Then you don't need anything extra in the connection string.

You can set the `search_path` for a given user (applies to all DBs in the DB cluster):

```
ALTER ROLE my_app1_user SET search_path = app1,public;
```

**Or** set the `search_path` only for the given role in the given database:

```
ALTER ROLE my_app1_user IN DATABASE tst SET search_path = app1,public;
```

**Or**, if your user name happens to be **`app1`**, then the search path setting
`"$user", public` resolves to `app1, public` automatically, and you don't need to do *anything* extra.

See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Thanks this works. However, I had to remove quotes (otherwise it doesn't work).So, the URL should be like this: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tst?currentSchema=app1,public. May be you can correct your answer as it took me a few minutes before I figure out the quotes issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using python/psycopg2/SQLAlchemy, I had to use

```
postgresql://localhost:5432/tst?options=-c%20search_path=app1,public
```

Comment: = near search_path needs to be encoded as %3D , otherwise psycopg2 throws:
"error when trying to initialize the conenction extra key/value separator "=" in URI query parameter: "options""